# How can I insert a row with an id, where the id is not already taken?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

So I'm in the slow process of becoming comfortable with databases.

(Example) I have two tables, customers and purchases. Created like this:

`create table Customers (customerId int, firstname varchar(255), surname varchar(255))`

`create table Purchases (customerId int, productName varchar(255))`

Let's say that some application wants to register a **new** customer. The new customer needs an id that does not already exist in the table.

If I execute this query: `insert into Customers values (1, 'Mark', 'Zuckerberg')`, there may already exist a different customer with this id.

How can the application obtain an value for `customerId` that does not already exist in the table? Is there something flawed with the design of this database? Should I be using some other method for tying purchases to customers?

Comment: Use a sequence, auto increment or identity column. Whatever your DBMS products supports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using `integer primary key autoincrement` as type for `customerId`.

```
create table Customers (
    customerId integer primary key autoincrement,
    firstname varchar(255),
    surname varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: In the end, I just removed this column altoghter. I use the built-in `rowid` column instead.